# What is "RewriteRule ^.* /sitename:::144.html? [L,R=301]" actually doing?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

What the effect of the following code is?

```
RewriteRule ^.* /site:::144.html? [L,R=301]
```

I couldn't find any matching entries in Google explaning the same.

Answer (score 0):

It matches any request `^.*` (“starts with any number of any arbitrary character”), and redirects it to `/site:::144.html`.

The question mark at the end of the target means any existing query string of the original request will be discarded.

The `L` flag means this will be the last rule interpreted in the current round of rewriting (when configured in .htaccess, the rewriting process “loops”, until no more rules match the current internal request),

and `R=301` means it will use status code 301 for a permanent redirect.